# ASP.NET Core 7 mix shared and dedicated localization resources

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, localization

I have a solution with around 40 views and controller where I use dedicated files for localizations. But now I need to add a common file to place translation used in multiple view without duplicating them in multiple files.

Looking at official documentation, I found that config

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options => {
            options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
        });
}
```

but with this note

> In the preceding code, `SharedResource` is the class corresponding to the .resx file where the validation messages are stored. With this approach, DataAnnotations only uses `SharedResource`, rather than the resource for each class.

Is there a documented way for a workaround to mix the two approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But now I need to add a common file to place translation used in
> multiple view without duplicating them in multiple files.

Based on the codes you've shown,I think you've messed up View localization and DataAnnotations localization

The codes:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options => {
            options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
        });
```

just relpaced the default DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider(`IStringLocalizer<T>`) with

```
IStringLocalizer<SharedResource>
```

but if you try with ViewLocalizer, you could choose the localizer in View yourself ,and they could work together well,for example,I tried as below:

[image]

[image]

tried as below in Index View:

```
@inject IViewLocalizer locallizer
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<SharedResource> sharedlocalizer
<h3>@locallizer["Hi"]</h3>
<h3>@sharedlocalizer["Hi"]</h3>
```

Result:
[image]

If you want your controller and view share the same resource,just inject the localizer into controller:

[image]

Comment: IHtmlLocalizer<SharedResource> is what i miss. is there a way to share resources also between views and controllers?

Comment: @gt.guybrush，Of,course you could ,just inject it into your controller,you could check what i've updated in my answer

Comment: sharedResourceS in view should be referenced to class or resx generated class?

Comment: sharedResourceS could be referred to class,and what your resx generated class mean?

Comment: sorry, i mean .cs class generated by visual studio